# Windows users having problems connecting to an Ubuntu-based SAMBA server

Tags: samba

I'm setting up a Samba file server on Ubuntu server 16.04 and wish to access shared folders on Windows 7 and Windows 10 PCs.

I can access any shared folder when `alexr` is the valid user defined in `smb.conf`, but I cant access the samba network using `Bek`'s credentials. Windows gives me the following msg when I try to access through `RUN \\nework location`:

> …Bek is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this
>   network resource...Multiple connections to a server or shared resource
>   by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed.
>   Disconnect all previous connections…and try again.

The above error msg has 2 parts. Either user `Bek` doesn’t have permission or there are multiple connections which are not allowed. I’m not sure which is my problem.

The following screen shots are from `smb.conf` showing shared folder settings, and the output of listing samba users with pbedit. Thanks for any help in advance.

[image: smb.conf]

[image: samba users (only showing Bek)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an annoyance I've had several times in the past with Windows.  Basically when you connect to the share under the `alexr` user, Windows cached the username for that user.  Even though it prompts you for more credentials, it still thinks that `alexr` is connected to the server, and refuses to connect you due to the cached credentials.  If you run: `net use`, you should see the connection to the server already established.  You can the use: `net use /delete <Path to share>` to remove the connection.  After that is complete, you should be able to try connecting with `Bek`.

Edit:
To answer your question about allowing multiple connections to the same server, (you edited my post as a response):  A possible work around is to use the IP address of the server or have aliases for the server and make two separate connections to them.  For example, have one connect via the IP address of the server, and the second connection connect via the hostname of the server.  You can read about these workarounds [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938120).

Comment: After an hour. A bloody hour. Thanks man, you are a life saver.